# GWT: encode url with encoding scheme

Tags: gwt, iso-8859-1

Is it possible to encode a url-parameter using a specific encoding scheme in GWT?

```
URLEncoder.encode(string, "ISO-8859-1");
```

works for me in standard java but isn't available in GWT.

```
URL.encode(string);
```

encodes in GWT with "UTF-8".
An encoding can not be specified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible. Take a look [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.org.google.gwt/41682)